# Linkage Error while starting WildFly

Tags: java, wildfly, linkageerror

I have a dependency JAR that i copy into APP-INF/lib directory which is listed in **application.xml** file as `<library-directory>APP-INF/lib</library-directory>`

When ever i try to start the server i get following error
 [image]

Can anybody please help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at:
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Class+Loading+in+WildFly

Our deployment structure looks essentially like this:

```
my.ear
  + lib/ <-- dependencies for multi-submodule deployment
  + META-INF/ <-- application.xml defines submodule(s) e.g. web.war, 
              <-- also jboss-deployment-structure.xml to include/export wildfly core modules for your EAR
  + web.war <-- our core deployment
```

I think in your case, you could just deploy your JARs to EAR/lib and they should be found across all submodules. From the Wildfly docs "Sub deployments (wars and ejb-jars) always have a dependency on the parent module, which gives them access to classes in EAR/lib"

Comment: In my deployment there is no 'lib' directory under my.ear. I tried creating a 'lib' directory and adding dependency to that but classes from that JAR was not available to the server application.